# Strange iboutlet error for my xib custom component (unwrapping an Optional value)

Tags: ios, swift, xib

Hi I m passing my viewModel from my controller to my AddToBasketView custom xib but I m not sure configure method is it true because sometimes my view appear in my viewcontroller but there was not data and also I'm getting an error unwrapping an Optional value and here is my codes;

Note: I call setupAddToBasketView func from my presenter.

**AddToBasketView**

```
final class AddToBasketView: UIView {

@IBOutlet private weak var discountedPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var discounteInfoStackView: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet private weak var discountedPercantage: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var originalPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var addToFavorite: UIButton!
@IBOutlet private weak var addToFavoriteBackView: UIView!
@IBOutlet private weak var addToBasket: UIButton!
@IBOutlet private weak var addToBasketBackView: UIView!

// MARK:- Constants
private enum Constants {
    enum Color {
        static let greenColor = UIColor("51AB5C")
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.configureView()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

private func configureView() {
    guard let view = self.loadFromNib(nibName: "AddToBasketView") else { return }
    view.frame = self.bounds
    self.addSubview(view)
}

func configure(with viewModel: ProductDetailViewModel?) {
    guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
    
    addToBasketBackView.layer.cornerRadius = 8 // Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
    addToFavoriteBackView.layer.cornerRadius = addToFavoriteBackView.frame.height / 2
    
    addToBasket.backgroundColor = UIColor("\(viewModel.cart?.addToCart?.backgroundColor ?? "")")
    addToBasket.setTitle(viewModel.cart?.addToCart?.text, for: .normal)
    
    discounteInfoStackView.isHidden = viewModel.discountedPrice.1
    discountedPrice.attributedText = viewModel.discountedPrice.0?.strikeThrough()
    discountedPercantage.text = viewModel.discountedRate
    discountedPercantage.textColor = Constants.Color.greenColor
    
    originalPrice.textColor = (viewModel.discountedPrice.1 ? .black : Constants.Color.greenColor)
    originalPrice.text = viewModel.originalPrice
}
```

}

**ViewController**

```
    func setupAddToBasketView() {
    let addToBasketView = AddToBasketView(frame: .zero)
    addToBasketView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    self.view.addSubview(addToBasketView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        addToBasketView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 85),
        addToBasketView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        addToBasketView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
        addToBasketView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -12)
        
    ])
    
    addToBasketView.configure(with: self.viewModel)
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: When doing `let addToBasketView = AddToBasketView(frame: .zero)`, are you sure that you are initializing the AddToBasketView with its xib (and all the IBOutlet)? I'm not sure about that... And that would explain the error when you are trying to access the IBOutlet, if not initialized with a xib where there has IBOutlet connected, then there will be nil.

Comment: @Larme yes I can initialize it like that why not? when put in the comment line for addToBasketView.configure(with: self.viewModel) method in ViewController there is no crash and I can see my all outlets.

Comment: @matt I'm getting an error unwrapping an Optional value...

Comment: Could you show a screenshot on where did you InterfaceBuilder of the Xib where you set the IBOutlet? Did you connect `addToBasketBackView` IBOutlet correctly?

Comment: I'm trying to find the part of your code where you tell us what line you got an error on and what the rror was, but I don't see it. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yeah I connect it correctly screenshots, https://ibb.co/RgYzSvF,
https://ibb.co/6rbv3Zg

Comment: @matt addToBasketBackView.layer.cornerRadius = 8 // Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value,    this line but when I comment addToBasketView.configure(with: self.viewModel) this line there is no crash but I cannot set data to my label (urls: ibb.co/RgYzSvF, ibb.co/6rbv3Zg)

Comment: It sounds to me like you don't understand your own code. Your AddToBasketView cannot come from an outlet. It has to be created in code. Otherwise, `self.configureView()` is never called.